# XPS13 - White screen on boot

Tags: boot, 19.04, white-screen

I have an XPS 13 9380 which was working quite well. In the last few days I cannot boot it anymore. When booting I end up in a white screen with some rubbish in the upper left corner.

I have manage to boot it in safe mode but I cannot work out yet where it is failing when booting in normal mode.

- Are there any known issues in the last week that affect XPS 13?
- any tips for diagnosing this kind of problems?